# Add unknown parameter to RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I stuck with the using of **RedirectToRouteResult**.
I want to redirect an action call inside a ActionFilterAttribute.
To achive this I need to overgive the parameter from the base called action.

I tried it this way:

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary {
        { "controller", "Controller" }
        , { "action", "Action" }
        , { "routeValues", filterContext.ActionParameters }
        });
[...]
```

But as result I get:

`http://localhost:81/Action?routeValues=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D`

What is the correct way to generate a redirect with a unknown list of parameter?

Regards Steffen